# Accessing class data outside of scope

Tags: swifty-json

I'm using `swift (2.3)`, and I've run into an issue accessing a variable I've created.

I'm trying to get the updated contents of `namesArray`

I'm able to get the JSON data (via `readableJSON`) from my class, via 1) `let.pdf = getData..`, and then 2) `pfd.getPetData...`

But I can't quite figure out how to feed my newly populated `namesArray` back outside of this "scope" (is that the right term?) so that I can access it outside of `super.viewDidLoad`.

Ultimately, I'd like the count of the array to go to:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return namesArray.count    
}
```

Here's the core area, minutes the tableView stuff.

```
import UIKit
import SwiftyJSON
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate {

    var namesArray = [String]()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad() 

        let pfd = getData()

        pfd.getPetData { readableJSON in

            for (key,subJson) in readableJSON[]["data"] {
                let title = subJson["title"].string!
                namesArray.append(title) 
            } 
        }
        print("There are \(self.namesArray.count) items in namesArray now")
    }

    class getData {
        func getPetData(completion: (JSON) -> ()) {
            let url = NSURL(string: "<my_JSON_URL_HERE>
            let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
            let readableJSON = JSON(data:data!)
            completion(readableJSON)
            }
            task.resume()

        }
    }
```

Would really appreciate anyone's thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `IBOutlet` of your table view in your `ViewController`. Reload your tableview here:

```
for (key,subJson) in readableJSON[]["data"] {
                let title = subJson["title"].string!
                namesArray.append(title) 
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
```

Comment: You need to add an `IBOutlet` of your `TableView` from your storyboard to your class. Only then you will be able to reload and perform table view operations.

Comment: When I added this, I'm getting the error message:

`"Ambiguous reference to member 'tableview(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)'"`

Had to add a "self":

Comment: Like I said, You need to add an `IBOutlet` of your `TableView` to your class.

Comment: I'll update my answer with this help. :). If it actually worked, mark the answer correct so that it can help others too.

Comment: Will do.  Thanks once again.  :-)